# Sympy does not recognise when two partial derivatives happen to be equal

Tags: python

I am trying to find the first and second-order partial derivatives of a function of four variables $S$ using pythons symbolic math package sympy.

The issue is that sympy does not automatically see that certain pairs of partial derivatives, **when evaluated at the same arguments**, are in fact equal, and so cancellations do not occur. For example:
$$\frac{\partial S(x,y,u,v)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial S(u,v,x,y)}{\partial u} \text{ when } x=u \text{ and } y=u.$$
You can see that in each case the functions are differentiated w.r.t their first arguments (x, u respectively) and that afterwards each partial derivative is evaluated at (x,y,x,y).

However, the code below returns `False`:

`sympy.diff(S(x, y, u, v), x).subs({u: x, v: y}) == sympy.diff(S(u, v, x, y), u).subs({u: x, v: y})`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should substitute before differentiating:

`sympy.diff(S(x, y, u, v).subs({u: x, v: y}), x) == sympy.diff(S(u, v, x, y).subs({u: x, v: y}), u)`

Comment: Substitution and differentiation are not commutable in general. Take for example $f(x,y)=x+y$. Then $$\left.\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right|_{y=x} = 1 \neq 2 = \frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial x}$$